# Can I recover windows after Ubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation, backup

I am not the best guys in the world with computers...

However, I was wondering, if it is possible to make a full installation of ubuntu on my pc, and make a backup of the windows 8 currently on it.

If I one day would regret my installation of ubuntu, would it be possible to install windows from the backup I made, and use the same product key, or is it not?

(I wanna erase windows if I install ubuntu... Only want one OS :D)

I would just hate it, if i lost the Windows I got on the pc when I bought it.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to install [Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) inside Windows on any of your NTFS partitions using [wubi installer](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe). This way you can keep your Windows installation, and have Ubuntu installed and/or removed like any other regular piece of software designed for windows. A wubi installation is as fast as a normal Ubuntu installation but you cannot allocate more than 30GB space for the whole thing. This is the only limitation, other than that you can test Ubuntu as long as you like, and when you decide it is time to get rid of Windows for good you can finally install Ubuntu for real.